What happens when you try to use more than 32 GB of memory-optimized data in a database on Standard Edition?
In SQL Server 2019, you cannot put more than 32 GB of memory-optimized data in a database on Standard Edition. What happens if you try anyway?
I'd try it myself, but I don't want to risk discovering that the answer is a knock on the door from the Licencing Police™.

I honestly don't know the answer and can only speculate it's likely an error either at the moment of attempting to do so or afterwards when trying to use said database (which is akin to how Express Edition works when you exceed the 10 GB database size limit). But I can assure you it's not "I don't want to risk discovering that the answer is a knock on the door from the Licencing Police™", so feel free to test for yourself, if you wish.

Agree with @J.D., my first thought was the error similar that throws Express Edition when you try to allocate data pages over 10Gb, the second is, no error is thrown but it just stops at 32Gb similar as you set up Express Edition on pc with 128 Gb of RAM but only 1Gb is in use

If "the answer is a knock on the door from the Licencing Police" then you don't need to worry, they are unlikely to turn up and are definitely not going to notice this if they do.


I'd try it myself, but I don't want to risk discovering that the answer is a knock on the door from the Licencing Police™.

This limit, like all the edition-related limitations in SQL Server, is enforced by the product itself.
It's your responsibility to make sure you have appropriate licenses for the version you install.  But then any edition-related limitations will be enforced, and so you can't accidentally violate the license.

"is enforced by the product itself" - But how? What specifically happens when I hit the limit?

Reading the table may fail.  Just like if you try to load an in-memory table that’s larger than your available memory on Enterprise Edition.
